# How do I use delegate - anonymous delegate - in CLI :: C++?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, c++-cli

I've got a C++/CLI application - and i using MVVM pattern.
Every so often I'd like it to post it's event to the main GUI. 
I've make a connection between the GUI and the button event SO if the button event is raised i could make the close dialog - but I'm struggling to convert the syntax from C# to C++:

```
 viewModel->OKButtonCommand += delegate
 {
         dialogResult = System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK;
         dlg->Close();
 };

viewModel->CancelButtonCommand += delegate
{
         dialogResult = System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Cancel;
         dlg->Close();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no anonymous delegate in C++/CLI. You'll have to convert the delegate to a normal class method and reference it that way.